# Conditionally using a css class in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js

I want it to use CSS style of margin-top = 5vh and margin-bottom = 7vh when `displayConfig.minCard` is `true` and and margin-top = 9vh and margin-bottom = 9vh when `displayConfig.minCard` is `false`

```
  .workflowSelectionMin{
    margin-top: 5vh;
    margin-bottom: 7vh;
  }

  .workflowSelection{
    margin-top: 9vh;
    margin-bottom: 9vh;
  }
```

I'm trying to use the v-bind to try to conditionally pick the css style but it seems like it's not working.

```
<div class="md-layout md-gutter  md-alignment-center-center" v-bind:style= "[displayConfig.minCard ? {workflowSelectionMin} : {workflowSelection}]">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```html
<div :class="[ displayConfig.mindCard ? 'workflowSelectionMin' : 'workflowSelection', 'md-layout', 'md-gutter', 'md-alignment-center-center' ]">
```

Take a look at the [array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)